# jQuery.FilterTable doesn't work on a table created with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I found this plugin [JQuery.FilterTable](https://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/) for searching on a table bun when i put at my table doesn't work .
I don't know what is the problem but from my opinion i think is because the table is made with PHP and the datas for table are from database.
The code lis like this:

```
<div class="issue-table">
<table class="table table-striped" id="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" title="President Number">Nr:</th>
            <th scope="col">Brand</th>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>
            <th scope="col">Color</th>
            <th scope="col">Release date</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <?php  
                if ($user->data()->type == 1) {
                    echo "<th>Delete</th>";
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php   
            $x = 1;
            foreach ($car as $index => $car_val) {
                $cars = DB::table('brands')->get(['id','=',$car_val->id_make]);
                $car_name = $cars->first()->name;
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$x++."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$car_name."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$car_val->model."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$car_val->color."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$car_val->release_date."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$car_val->value."</td>";
                if ($user->data()->type == 1) {
                    echo 
                    "<td>
                        <form action='index.php?page=carlist' method='POST'>
                            <input type='hidden' value='".$car_val->id."' name='id'>
                            <input type='submit' value='X' class='btn btn-danger'>
                        </form>
                    </td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I used this code but isn't working:

```
<script>
   $('table').filterTable(); 
</script>
```

How can I make this plugin to work?

Comment: How does it "not work"? Is the filter input area not displaying? Is it displaying but not reacting when you type filter criterion?

Comment: The input is not displaying.How can i make it?

Comment: So maybe one of your `<script>`s have a wrong `src` URL. Reading about the FilterTable plugin I wanted to look at their examples and I just noticed that some of their links lead to a page where it didn't work (exactly like it happens for you): go to [this page](https://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/examples/filtertable-quick.html) and you'll see that the filter area is missing. It comes from the `http**s**`, which prevents the jQuery script to be loaded. Simply change it for `http` and the filter area appears.

Comment: Ok I will search for the http**s** and change to http .I will notice if doesn't work.